# How to set DataView template arguments

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I extend for example `Ext.button.Button` component, I know how I can pass parameters to the template. I do it like so:

```
renderTpl: '...{custom_parameter}...',
getTemplateArgs: function() {
    return {
        custom_parameter: "Some value"
    }
}
```

It works good. But now I want to do the same trick when extending `Ext.DataView`. Lets suppose I have some template defined like so:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    ...
    tpl: [
        '<div>{custom_parameter}</div>',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            ...
        '</tpl>'
    ] 
    ...
```

I see that `DataView` is missing this nice `getTemplateArgs`. So what is the alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to initialize the template in initConfig/constructor so that you can pass the dataview's config options to the template.

```
templateArgs: {
    custom_parameter: "Some value"
},    
initConfig: function () {
    this.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div>{[this.templateArgs.custom_parameter]}</div>',
        '<tpl for=".">',
                ...
        '</tpl>',
        {
            templateArgs: this.templateArgs
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah! I managed to implement this with the help of constructor. Thanks!